# Regular expression warning rule cannot be matched

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexer

I have defined regular expressions for :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+  {yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return hostname;}
[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*  {yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return variable;}
```

and I get a lexer warning, rule cannot me matched.

I understand this warning comes when two rules are similar.

But I intend to have:
Hostname: Can contain ASCII alphanumeric characters, periods, underscores and hyphens.
Variable: Can contain ASCII alphanumeric characters and underscores but first character must not be a number.

I feel I have defined it according to the rules. Then why this warning? Also, though it is only a warning my code does not work so cannot ignore this!

Answer (score 1):

Is:

```
word
```

a variable or a hostname? How do you know? It certainly matches both patterns.

In fact, *any string* which matches your `variable` pattern will also match your `hostname` pattern.

Since `hostname` comes first in your flex definition, it takes priority, which means that any string which matches both `hostname` and `variable` will be reported as a `hostname`. Consequently, it is impossible that any string will be reported as a `variable` and that is what flex is warning you about.

You need to describe your criteria for deciding between `variable` and `hostname` when both match. Otherwise, you cannot get a resolution to this problem.

Comment: I have moved the "variable" definition above the "hostname" definition. This did not give any warnings. but my programs behaves in an unexpected way giving dumb errors. Are the two definitions wrong? How do I define both seperately?

Comment: As I said, you need to decide what you expect for a string which matches both patterns. Flex always chooses exactly one action; you cannot return "either hostname or variable".